# Please how to find indefinite integral $\int x^{x^x}\mathrm dx$?

Tags: integration

Please how to find indefinite integral

$$\int x^{x^x}\mathrm dx$$
Thank for any one help me to find it

Comment: Why do you expect a nice closed form for the antiderivative to exist?

Comment: Source?${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Clayton, such functions (and their derivatives and integrals) did intrige me when in my calculus classes. Sadly, there was no http://math.stackexchange.com around in those days. Don't quench the kid's curiosity.

Comment: @vonbrand: I'm not sure if you thought I was trying to be rude; I was simply curious myself.

Comment: @Clayton, I don't believe you tried to be rude, it just came across that it could be interpreted that way to me.

Comment: @vonbrand, we can choose less abrupt language for asking, but it will always be helpful to know the background of a question. Especially in the middle ground, if I think I might be able to contribute but am not sure of solving a problem without a good deal of work: for example, see my forlorn comments at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296931/find-x-such-that-1213x-be-a-perfect-square#comment645600_296931  Sometime before that, i put related language in my user profile.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is possible for the definite integrals as  (in the sense of getting an alternative form)
$$\int_0^1 x^x \mathrm{dx} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^n} $$
and then we can think of a generalization of sophomore’s dream integral/series identities.
In the spirit of this way I think you're also interested in this [useful paper.](http://www.m-hikari.com/ijma/ijma-2010/ijma-29-32-2010/vangorderIJMA29-32-2010.pdf)

Comment: I personally worked on $\int_0^1 x^{x^x}\mathrm dx$, but dropped it out after a while since things became rather complicated. Thanks to those that didn't give up! :-)

Comment: In fact, the requested integral (but evaluated from 0 to 1) is Case 5 with $a=b=1$ in the paper you cite.

Comment: @RossMillikan: yeah, I know.

Answer (score 1):

For your reference:${}{}{}{}{}$

http://hk.knowledge.yahoo.com/question/question?qid=7008010201949